# Homepage effect

Tags: html, css

I would like to know : how to recreate the effect or the content page comes to cover the homepage ? http://visia.themes.tf/

I tried with "background: fixed" but it doesn't work on iPhone. While the theme visia works perfectly on iPhone.

I tried to see the code source (ctrl + u on chrome). But I didn't find the properties of #home id.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is. At line 89 `<section id="home" class="home-first-section hero clearfix">`

Comment: Thank you but I didn't find the properties of #home and home-first-section in the css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .header {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .header img {
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .content {
        background: #FFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        z-index: 2
    }
```

**JSFIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/jmtdjv19/6/

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately background-attachement doesn't work on iPhone

Comment: ok, i have an solution for this :D

Comment: Ah ok what solution ? :D

Comment: Sorry currently i have a lot to do...we must put the image absolutley positioned with z-index lower that the content.

Comment: The basic concept is that ..currently i'm very busy sorry..with a bit of jquery or vanilla.js it would be simple